# Rasterize TrueType Character Glyph Data

Tags: fonts, rendering, truetype, raster, glyph

I have a character's glyph data from the *glyf table* in a TrueType font file.
This data is represented as a block of decimal numbers.

*Example:* character 'a' in Calibri 11pt (Glyph Index 258)

```
0209225523736332020510640176643215663166476631192352121217752161317752241117752161516176521841247641403939150112016151770581842552401791217758184255232179131775818425523217911177581842552321801516176581842864201723197052165225919252105215252466542184127641520834134344292344674612201277404763237632371857479323717185747931139493237147225434343431964394935747162254343434350574948949337206635343838535366353446253526225151535246235341423534462535262451503022173534142212022515054553631628272631145914581711158145621161681051242249785761977349128129472766861025297136843816414168100663189806511161241212661212906370377010265761127437705280532729352981625152529263529194485126841962345634170836668
```

What are the possibilities to *draw* this character on a screen?

Comment: good question. I did a quick search and could not find any useful information about this. Hope somebody will have an answer to this on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: don't do this yourself. Use a font rendering library such as [freetype](http://freetype.org/), or if you are on a platform that already has a font renderer, use that. There are also a number of commercial rendering libraries available.

Long answer: the data specification for decoding the glyph data into curves (plus, optionally, instructions) can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/glyf.htm). So you can start with that. But you'll need much, much more...You'll also minimally need to parse the 'head' and 'hhea' tables to know where to place things and how to scale design units into the drawing space. Then you'll need to parse the 'fpgm', 'cvt ', and 'prep' tables which contain "global" (font-wide) instructions (sometimes referred to as "hints"). Then you'll need to parse the instructions that are present in each glyph, then develop a fill routine to use all of this information to place the individual pixels. Good luck! This is not for the faint-hearted nor those looking for a quick solution. Use a library.